# How do I plot an entire Pandas DataFrame under the same label?

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I am attempting to write a plotting function that takes 2 arguments - a DataFrame and a label `(df1 and label1)`. My function also has optional arguments to add more DataFrames if I have more groups of data to plot:

```
def REE_GroupPlot(df1, label1,
                  df2=None, label2=None, 
                  df3=None, label3=None, 
                  df4=None, label4=None,
                  df5=None, label5=None):
```

I am trying to plot all of the columns in a single DataFrame under the same key label and as the same color, but I am not quite sure how. I have looked into `pd.groupby`, but I can't seem to make it do what I want.

I would appreciate any suggestions - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What if you pass in an list of dataframes like

```
def REE_Group_Plot(dfs, label):
      # combine all dataframes into 1
      all_dfs = pd.concat(dfs)

     # the rest of the code to plot the graph



REE_Group_Plot(dfs=[df, df2, df3, df4], label = “ABC”)
```

Comment: That's a good idea, I didn't think to try that! I'll give it a go and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I think that part of the issue is that I would like each data frame I pass to have a unique label

Comment: Each dataframe will have their own color and label? Are you using matplotlib?

Comment: Yeah, I am using Matplotlib. I also get an error 'setting an array element with a sequence.' Should I make my labels a list too?